# I am trying to set my default zoom in in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Below is my code. I am trying to have my map start off by being zoomed in to a certain number in xcode. It doesn't seem to work that way. Every time I open the map now, it's completely zoomed out to a point where you can see the entire continent. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class YogaMap: UIViewController{

   @IBOutlet weak var Yoga: MKMapView!

   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 100

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }

    func setupLocationManager(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func centerViewOnUserLocation(){
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate{
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            Yoga.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func checkLocationServices(){
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {

        }
    }
    func checkLocationAuthorization(){
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:

            centerViewOnUserLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }

    }
}

extension YogaMap: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

  }
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for location manager to return a location before trying to use `centerViewOnUserLocation`. Try moving your function call inside `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

Comment: I tried this but nothing
extension YogaMap: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      centerViewOnUserLocation()
  }
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

You forgot call `startUpdatingLocation` in this function `func setupLocationManager`

```
func setupLocationManager(){
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Center map view when your location update

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    centerViewOnUserLocation()
}
```